# AttributeError: 'BertConfig' object has no attribute '_commit_hash'

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I did fine-tune my BERT models during past few months and they worked pretty fine till 3 days ago. But today I'm receiving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'BertConfig' object has no attribute '_commit_hash'
```

I didn't change ANYTHING. I'm just Using my previous code and model that I've been using until now with no problem. I even changed TensorFlow to the previous version but it still doesn't work. I also searched the internet but there was no similar error. Does anyone have any idea what's the problem and how can I fix this, please?

Note: I'm using **Colab**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask